# ECW support in QGIS server

Tags: qgis-server, ecw

I have followed the instruction on the web page

https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/adding-ecw-support-in-qgis/

to add ECW support to QGIS but it seems to have no effect on QGIS server. I cannot see the raster layers in a QGIS project when I query the QGIS server capabilities. I have also noticed that the raster layers are not listed when using some other raster formats, but they are listed if I use TIFF, or IMG format.

Comment: I suspect you are coming up against a need for server licensing which I would expect to be much more expensive than desktop.

Comment: I thought QGIS administrator and server were completely free.

Comment: I'm not a QGIS user but I would have expected that the ECW support would require an independent and commercial license from Hexagon Geospatial.

Comment: ECW licence is distributed with QGIS. Usage on server is not free and I believe that QGIS Mapserver is automatically disabling the driver.

Comment: Here is a part of ECW license: `1.9. ``Server Application'' means software products that You develop or
maintain and are capable of running on a Server to provide an image
decoding or processing capability. This License Agreement does not
authorize You to use the SDK to create Server Applications.`

Comment: Came across the same 'issue' - I exported to gpkg and served that.